# PHP Read text file until break when match condition

Tags: php

I would like to read text file in PHP which break or exit after match condition.

PHP CODE:

```
$file = fopen("testFile.txt", "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
//Output a line of the file until the end is reached
while(!feof($file))
{

    $line = fgets($file, 1024); 
    if($line=="NOTE"){
        break;
    }
    echo $line ."<br>";

}
fclose($file);
```

**Example**

```
line1: i love u so much
line2: this is tom
Line3: note
Line: this is jam
```

**Result need :**

**when meet note will be break.**

```
line1: i love u so much
line2: this is tom
```

Comment: What output are you getting? What output are you expecting to get? How does the file look?

Comment: Example

line1: i love u so much

line2: this is tom

Line3: note

Line: this is jam

Result need :

when meet note will be break.

line1: i love u so much

line2: this is tom

Comment: line 3 `note` or `NOTE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I gather you can have different cases, and like mario said you also have endlines. You should check like this:

```
if(strtolower(trim($line)) == "note"){
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The lines you get from `fgets()` still include the trailing newline. So you either have to check against the trimmed line:

```
 if (trim($line) == "NOTE")
```

Or if you are certain of the linebreak variant (\n or \r\n) the exact line:

```
 if ($line == "NOTE\r\n") {
```

Further alternatives include strncmp() if you only want to check the start of the line for NOTE, or strstr() or strpos() if you want to check for presence somewhere in the line.

Comment: also.. case sensitivity should be taken care of

Comment: After the edit not sure what the question is about anymore. But strtolower(), strncasecmp(), stristr() or stripos() would be the next alternatives then.

Comment: @JamSva if it worked, you should mark this answer as the one that worked for you. (The little checkmark on the left). Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend `file_get_contents`:

```
$sFile = file_get_contents("testFile.txt") or die("Unable to open file!");
$sFile = preg_replace(array("/\r\n/", "/\r/", "/\n/"), "<br />", $sFile); //array because of some fixes
$sFile = preg_replace("/<br \/>(\s+)?Note(\s+)?(<br \/>.+|$)/i", "<br />", $sFile);
echo $sFile;
```